# A Code That's a Little Bit Weird

Tags: knowledge, cipher

The street outside Rockefeller Center was a very busy place to hide a secret message, I thought, but sometimes the best place to hide something was in plain sight.  I'm a government agent, from one of those alphabet agencies, investigating corruption in international song competitions. I was going to meet an unknown contact for information, but first I had been told to find a message here.

The note I had to find was taped to the bottom of a park bench; standard stuff, really.  I recovered the note and opened it to find the following handwritten message.

> WHERE ARE YOU?
>
> ← → ← →
>
> DMUQBAA ZPBLKBKL: KJEOQDMYB
>
> KEEP MOVING!

I obeyed the final message, walking to meet up with my contact in a bar nearby.  But I didn't know anything about them!  Perhaps the cyphertext would give me information, or at let me know who I was looking for.

***What does the message say?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message says:

> `CONTACT CODENAME: NIGHTCORE`

Method:

> Split the ciphertext into groups of 4 letters. For every group, shift the first letter alphabetically to the left by 1, the second letter to the right by 2, third letter to the left by 7 and fourth letter to the right by 3 (directions indicated by the arrows in the note)
>  (This is equivalent to a Vigenere cipher with the key 'BYHX')

Why:

> There are multiple references to the [Eurovision Song Contest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurovision_Song_Contest) in this puzzle: E.g. "international song competition", "[WHERE ARE YOU?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_Are_You%3F_(Imaani_song))" and most notably "Rockefeller Center", "Keep moving" and "A little bit weird", which is a reference to the song [Rockefeller Street](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockefeller_Street), which was also part of the ESC in 2011 ("Keep moving" and "a little bit weird" are part of the lyrics)
>  The chorus of the song features the line "1273, down the Rockefeller street", which, combined with the arrows, is the key for the cipher.
>  [Nightcore versions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hjGZLnja1o8) of this song are especially popular.